# Execution failed when building OpenSSL: returned exit code 1

Tags: pyqt, pyqtdeploy

Execution failed when building OpenSSL: returned exit code 1, how should I deal with this problem?

Hello, this is my first time using pyqtdeploy. I am learning according to the user Guide. My python version is 3.6.7 and the pyqtdeploy version is 2.3.1.

According to the user Guide, I tried to compile pyqt-demo.py into an executable file. After I run pyqt-demo.py, the program runs as follows:

Demo program running result

[image]

Since the python version is 3.6.7, I adjusted the python configuration in sysroot.json as follows:

```
"python": {
    "build_host_from_source":   false,
    "build_target_from_source": true,
    "source":                   "Python-3.6.*.tar.xz"
},
```

I will adjust the python version in pyqt-demo.pdy as follows:

Pyqt-demo.pdy description

[image]

I downloaded openssl-1.1.1.tar.gz and Python-3.6.7.tar.xz

Current directory

[image]

Finally run

pyqtdeploy-sysroot sysroot.json

Sysroot.json is included in the demo, and the following problems occur:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\pyqtdeploy\pyqtdeploy-2.3.1\demo> pyqtdeploy-sysroot sysroot.json
Building OpenSSL
pyqtdeploy-sysroot: Execution failed: returned exit code 1
```

How can I solve this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to download all the files mentioned in the `sysroot.json` file and run. You can run the same command with `--verbose` to see clear error messages